# Why does this merge sort algorithm not work properly?

Tags: c++, mergesort

I get no errors or warnings. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r);

int main(){
    int arr[11] = {1, 9, 2, 5, 3, 10, 4, 8, 6, 7};

    mergeSort(arr, 0, 10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r){
    int i = l;      // starting point of left subarray
    int j = m + 1;  // starting point of right subarray
    int k = l;      // starting point of temporary array
    int temp[11];
    while(i <= m && j <= r){
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j]){
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i <= m){
        temp[k] = arr[i];
        k++; i++;
    }
    while(j <= r){
        temp[k] = arr[j];
        k++; j++;
    }
    for(int s = l; s < 11; s++){
        arr[s] = temp[s];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r){
    if(l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2; // middle
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); // left subarray
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); // right subarray
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I compile and run:

> 0       1       2       3       4       9       4199851 7208472 7667712 7669136 1996860265

It seems like the left part is sorted - although there's no 0 in the original array, and then everything messes up and the right part is all nonsense.

If anyone can help me out I'd really appreciate it - thank you.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `merge` only populates elements of `temp` between `l` and `r`, but copies into `arr` all elements from `l` to the end. It therefore overwrites `arr` with a bunch of uninitialized garbage.

Comment: There is too `0` in the original array. You declared it to have 11 elements but only provided 10 initializers. The last element is then zero-initialized.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik But doesn't l to r encompass the entire array? Isn't the 'r' in fact the end?

Comment: The problem is with the merge function. Please loop through `l` to `r` not `11`.

Comment: Not when `mergeSort(arr, l, m)` calls `merge` recursively to sort half of the original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the merge function. You have to loop through `l` to `r`, `inclusive` not `11`. Please see the reference code for a better understanding.

**Reference Code**

```
#include <iostream>

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r);

int main(){
    int arr[11] = {1, 9, 2, 5, 3, 10, 4, 8, 6, 7};

    mergeSort(arr, 0, 10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r){
    int i = l;      // starting point of left subarray
    int j = m + 1;  // starting point of right subarray
    int k = l;      // starting point of temporary array
    int temp[11];
    while(i <= m && j <= r){
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j]){
            temp[k] = arr[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            temp[k] = arr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i <= m){
        temp[k] = arr[i];
        k++; i++;
    }
    while(j <= r){
        temp[k] = arr[j];
        k++; j++;
    }
    for(int s = l; s <= r; s++){
        arr[s] = temp[s];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r){
    if(l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2; // middle
        mergeSort(arr, l, m); // left subarray
        mergeSort(arr, m + 1, r); // right subarray
        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Yes this has worked - thank you very much Badhan Sen!